# Grails picking old version jars(previous used) also, in 'test war' creation

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I used yesterday itext-2.0.8 and today i changed to itext-2.1.7. even it is picking 2.0.8 into war file also two versions of itext jars are coming in war file.    Now, there is no reference in pom or BuildConfig regarding 2.0.8, even it adding in war file.

Why it picking old referred jars and what bases it selecting which jars need to go for war file.

What should i do to eliminate them.

i deleted target folder and i run  grails clean, even same output.

i think, i have to manually delete the all itext-2.0.8 in maven repo(.m2) and grails repo(.grails).

please give me your valuable suggestions please

Comment: Is it possible that you have a plugin or any other dependency that has itext-2.0.8 as its dependency? Its being downloaded maybe because of transitive dependency. if so you need to tell that plugin/lib to exclude itext.

Comment: run the clean, refresh-dependencies targets  and also check your transitive dependencies if the problem persists.